# Primefaces rendered if list contains a value

Tags: java, primefaces, xhtml

```
<h:outputText rendered="#{bean.list.contains(watever)}" value="show this "/>
```

I want to use rendered to show some text if the list contains a specific  value, however i get a syntax error in eclipse saying that

> Method must have signature "boolean method(),  boolean method(String), boolean method(String, String), 
>    boolean method(String, String, String), boolean method(String, String, String, String), boolean method(String, 
>    String, String, String, String), boolean method(String, String, String, String, String, String), boolean 
>    method(String, String, String, String, String, String, String), ..............................
>   but has  signature "boolean method(Object)"

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Try a custom method in you bean, doing the same thing as `contains`method

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
<h:outputText rendered="#{bean.list.contains('watever')}" value="show this "/>
```

instead of ?

```
<h:outputText rendered="#{bean.list.contains(watever)}" value="show this "/>
```

Comment: ya I already tried it doesnot work but the work around in the comment works. The problem is that the contains methods it self takes an object so I had to make a similar method that takes string instead

Comment: For the `contains()` method to work, you need to override Object's `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods.